# Cast and Sum functions - PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, casting

I'm trying to find the sum of cast_cost, shelf_price and bottle_price, where the item description includes Scotch or Canadian Whiskey. However Bottle_price's value is a price, and not numeric like the other items in the select statement. At first I tried this query, and it returned an error because of bottle_price needing to be Cast differently.

```
select SUM(case_cost)+SUM(shelf_price)+SUM(bottle_price) as total
from public.products
where item_description ilike '%Scotch%' or item_description ilike '%Canad%';
```

Afterward, I created several different queries and kept getting error messaging. This is my most recent attempt at simply trying to get the casting right for bottle_price, and perhaps I included too many parenthesis, but I'm getting an error at the "AS" numeric section:

```
select (cast(sum (bottle_price AS numeric)))
from public.products
where item_description ilike '%Scotch%' or item_description ilike '%Canad%';
```

Can anyone help with this casting issue?

Comment: What's the actual data type of "Bottle_price"? (PostgreSQL doesn't have a data type named *price*.) What do the values in that column look like?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on desired result type it could be

```
SUM(case_cost)+SUM(shelf_price)+SUM(bottle_price)::numeric as total
```

for `numeric` result or

```
SUM(case_cost)::money+SUM(shelf_price)::money+SUM(bottle_price) as total
```

for `money` result.

Answer (score 1):

First  `cast` then `sum` the resulting numeric values

```
select sum(cast(bottle_price AS numeric))
from public.products
where item_description ilike '%Scotch%' or item_description ilike '%Canad%';
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
select (SUM(case_cost::numeric) + SUM(shelf_price::numeric) + SUM(bottle_price::numeric)
       ) as total
from public.products
where item_description ilike '%Scotch%' or item_description ilike '%Canad%';
```

I find the Postgres-specific `::` syntax for casting to be very convenient.  On the other hand, I find it strange that Postgres doesn't allow money to be added up (by default).